# How to remap pgup and pgdown to home and end Thinkpad X1 Carbon Ubuntu 13.10 Gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, 13.10, xmodmap

I have used the xmodmap technique, I even made a file called .Xmodmap and put it in the start up commands in the gnome tweak tool, but there are still occasions where the buttons don't perform what I specified. I know because opening my terminal and doing "xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap" fixes the behavior to what I need.

Any ideas on what might not be working right here?

Comment: Any help would rock.

Answer (score -1):

for linux mint you can use the last post in this topic. 
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=208&t=135999
also seems that using different type of loading (kdm or startx) is loading through different files so you should check if realy xinitrc is loaded at all . If not xinitrc then try .xsession may be. I didn't work for me though

Sorry . This should be rather comment but I don't have rights to do comments.
How it works for me on linux mint 17:

1. create remapkey (show have right to run 555 for example) file in /usr/lib/bin/
2. in start up programs I added

> bash /usr/local/bin/remapkey

command to start

3. in this file I have

> xmodmap $HOME/.Xmodmap